# Notation: select an element from a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For an academic publication, how does one denote selecting a single element from a set?

My closest attempt is $\{X \mid X \in \{X_1, X_2\}\}$, and I'm trying to say "select either $X_1$ or $X_2$ from the set and call this selected element "$X$", but I don't know if that's correct.

Comment: Let $X\in\{X_1,X_2\}$?  What you describe is actually $\{X_1,X_2\}$.

Comment: ...leave it to me to make things more complicated than they actually are...Thanks.

Comment: I have invented a notion for picking an element out of a not empty set A, namely $$choice A.$$

Comment: This corresponds to Bourbaki's $\iota$ notation in a way